# Multi-Row Solver Macro Not Updating Cell Values

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and am trying to develop a macro to apply Solver to multiple rows at the same time.  I was able to develop a script based on tutorials that works well if only one row is entered, however if I specify a range the script gets stuck in "setting up the problem..." and never actually executes.  Can someone please review my script and suggest any changes that might make it function better.  The alternative is running the script one row at a time for over 1000 rows.

```
  Sub SolverItter()

  Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

  Solverreset

  SolverOK setcell:="$G$42:$G$45", MaxMinVal:=2, ByChange:="$k$42:$K$45", engine:=1, enginedesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$I$42:$I$45", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="0.3"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$I$42:$I$45", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0.24"
    solversolve userfinish:=True

  End Sub
```

**Update (9Feb2018 2:10 GMT):**

I've tried adapting my script into a For statement based on nbayly's reply to [EricBayes's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31393758/excel-vba-run-solver-over-multiple-rows-using-a-loop/). This corrected the permanent "setting up problem..." issue I was having, however now the script fails to change the values of the "by changing" cells.  The below script seems closer to the answer to my problem, but is still doesn't work.

```
Sub SolverItter()

    Dim rngObjectCells As Range
    Set rngObjectCells = Range("$G$42:$G$61")

    Dim rngObjectCell As Range

    For Each rngObjectCell In rngObjectCells

        Solverreset

        Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

        SolverOK setcell:=rngObjectCell.Address, MaxMinVal:=2, ByChange:=rngObjectCell.Offset(0, 4).Range("$k$42:$K$61"), engine:=1, enginedesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
        SolverAdd CellRef:=rngObjectCell.Offset(0, 2).Address, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="0.33"
        SolverAdd CellRef:=rngObjectCell.Offset(0, 2).Address, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0.20"
        SolverAdd CellRef:=rngObjectCell.Offset(0, 1).Address, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="0.15"
        solversolve userfinish:=True
        SolverOK setcell:=rngObjectCell.Address, MaxMinVal:=2, ByChange:=rngObjectCell.Offset(0, 4).Range("$k$42:$K$61"), engine:=1, enginedesc:="GRG Nonlinear"

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with my script for a few days and getting a couple VBA books, I've figured out how to get this script to work.  Below is my explanation for anyone whose trying to figure out how to get a multi-row solver macro to work.

```
Sub MagmaMixer()

' Change Sheet1 to the name of the excel sheet you're using

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

' Set H16 to the first cell that you want the solver to set to the given 
' value

Range("H16").Select
Dim i As Integer

' Tells the For loop to run the solver for six rows beginning at H16
' Change the 6 to the number of rows you want to run solver for.

For i = 1 To 6
    SolverReset
    Set x = ActiveCell

' This is the nuts and bolts of the solver tool.  SetCell:=ActiveCell tells
' Solver that you want to set the active cell (set in the Range step above)
' to some value.  MaxMinVal:= identifies what you want to set the cell to, 
' where 1 is a maximum, 2 is a minimum, and 3 is a set value (ie 5).
' ByChange:=x.Offset(0,5) tells solver to accomplish the above by changing
' the value of the cell 0 columns and 5 rows to the right of the reference
' cell (ie M16 in this example).

    SolverOK SetCell:=ActiveCell, MaxMinVal:=2, _
    ByChange:=x.Offset(0, 5)


' SolverAdd applies additional constraints. The cell references are kept
' relative just like above.

    SolverAdd CellRef:=x.Offset(0, 4), Relation:=1, FormulaText:="0.32"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=x.Offset(0, 4), Relation:=2, FormulaText:="0.22"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=x.Offset(0, 1), Relation:=1, FormulaText:="0.10"

' userfinish:=True suppresses the end of solver popup windows.

    solversolve userfinish:=True

' Tells the macro to move the active cell to the next row.

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next i

End Sub
```